# Windows/Ubuntu game to play on a ethernet LAN

Tags: windows, ubuntu, game

I've set up a small home network using a switch, and a DHCP server to assing ips, and would like my girlfriend to be able to connect to the network and play a game together.

Is there a game we can download and play on a LAN (windows and linux)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've played several cross platform games that allow play over a LAN. To make a good recommendation depends a lot on what your preferences are and what type of game you are looking for. I'll just make a list and you can decide which games seem the most compelling and worth trying out. It might be worth checking to make sure your computer meets the minimum requirements before trying out a particular game as well.

**Minecraft Java Edition** https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/store/minecraft-java-edition multiplayer on Linux and Windows. It costs somewhere around $27 per copy. You can collect resources, build structures, and fight monsters. It is more polished than the open source options. Make sure to get the Java edition on both windows and linux because the Windows 10 edition does not cross play with the Java edition and only the Java edition will run on Linux.

The rest of these games are open source and free. I'll list them in order from the ones I've liked the most, but that's just my opinion. I honestly recommend all of them.

**SuperTuxKart** https://supertuxkart.net/Main_Page You drive a vehicle around a track and race your opponent, You can pickup powerups that help you or hinder your opponent. This game is very well polished and easy to use. I'd suggest it even if you don't play games often.

**OpenTTD** https://www.openttd.org/ You build train tracks, roads, and airports to transfer people and goods and complete contracts. As you make money you can invest it to improve your transportation system and grow the cities you service. Great game but it is a little confusing to figure out.

**0 A.D.** https://play0ad.com/ It has a bigger learning curve than most of the others and last I played it also felt a little less stable. Basically you train your troops and send them off to gather resources to train more troops. Once you have enough you send them out attack other players or use them to defend your city.

**Xonotic** https://xonotic.org/ First person shooter. My favorite mode is to put on energy lasers that insta-kill and enable the grappling hook to let me fly around the map like crazy. There are ways to make the game play a little bit slower as well. It might not be as much fun with just 2 people, but it is pretty straight forward to get the hang of.

**Armagetron Advanced** http://www.armagetronad.org/ You drive a futuristic motorcycle and can only make right turns. You lay down a wall behind you. If you run into a wall you explode (and loose). Try and cut off your opponents. If I remember right it lets you play with computer controlled opponents as well. Simple and straight forward to play although the menus are a bit confusing.

**Hedgewars** https://www.hedgewars.org/ You shoot weapons at your opponent by selecting the angle and power to shoot it at. The weapons generally explode on impact and destroy terrain around the explosion. Simple to use menus and it has a tutorial when you first start it up.

**Frozen Bubble** http://frozen-bubble.org/ I don't know that I've actually tested out the multiplayer on this one, but they claim it has the functionality on their website. You match colors on the frozen bubbles to knock them off. Knock off the right ones to send more bubbles to your opponents. Very simple point and click.

**Minetest** https://www.minetest.net/ Basically a free clone of minecraft. I've only played it for a few minutes but, like Minecraft, you collect resources and build structures. I didn't get to test out the LAN function but it looks like it probably works just fine. Online play works well. I needed to reference the online wiki to really figure it out.

There are some others I've heard about but never tried. They all say that they support multiplayer over LAN but since I've never tried them I don't actually know.

**Battle for Wesnoth** https://www.wesnoth.org/ Looks like a turn based game where you battle enemies and complete quests.

**Freeciv** http://www.freeciv.org/ Looks like a turn based straegy game where you build a civilization to try and out compete others.